# I need to remove site domain in my href link in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, dns

I have this code in html

```
  <a href="www.example.com"> Example </a>
```

then it shows in link

```
  http://localhost/www.example.com
```

Please help me remove this thing...

Comment: what do you want to remove ?

Comment: I want to remove http://localhost/ it should only show the link.

Comment: www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">Example</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
```